# MS Access summing single column in one row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to build a database in Access. I have created a user interface so the user can choose and enter data. In another table I need to sum one single column that has more than one row and give the me result.

Answer (score 0):

select sum(column_name) from tablename;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see detail records as well as total, options:

1. open table or query and click the Sigma(Totals) icon on ribbon Home tab to open a row at bottom of table/query where you can select aggregate functions under each column.
2. build a form or report with table or query as RecordSource, put a textbox in footer section with expression in its ControlSource: `=Sum(fieldname)`

If you are on a form that does not include that table in its RecordSource, can use domain aggregate functions in textbox expression to pull data from table.

This is all basic Access functionality.

Comment: i'm new in access this my first time using it. i also have another issue which is summing single column based on the user's choice from another table. for example, i have a that includes all  the prices.on the other hand i'm giving the user command to choose two products, how can i write a simple sql code to calculate the prices of these two products.

Comment: Start a new question. But since your questions do not have attempted code, might find a different forum to ask in. Have you completed an introductory tutorial book? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html